# What does the blue line represent on Yahoo Finance's day range graphics?

Tags: investing, stock-analysis

The rows of my Yahoo Finance watchlist table have a Day Range graphic like this one:
[image: Yahoo Finance screenshot]

The number labels under the left and right ends of the Day Range are the high and low prices for the day so I assume the gray line represents that range, and the blue arrow points to the current price.

What does the blue subsection of the gray line represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The oposite end of the blue line to the current possition of the arrow would represent the price at which the stock openned at for that day. So the total length of the blue line represents how far the current price is away from the open.

And if the arrow is to the left side of the blue line it means the current price is below the openning price. Conversly if the arrow was on the right side of the blue line it would mean that the current price is above the openning price.